# Java Regex with Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I am using Pattern and Matcher classes from Java ,
I am reading a Template text and I want to replace :

1. src="scripts/test.js" with src="scripts/test.js?Id=${Id}"
2. src="Servlet?Template=scripts/test.js" with src="Servlet?Id=${Id}&Template=scripts/test.js"

I'm using the below code to execute case 2. :

```
//strTemplateText  is the Template's text
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(?i)(src\\s*=\\s*[\"'])(.*?\\?)");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(strTemplateText);
strTemplateText = m2.replaceAll("$1$2Id=" +     CurrentESSession.getAttributeString("Id", "") + "&");
```

The above code works correctly for case 2. but how can I create a regex to combine both cases 1. and 2. ?

Thank you

Comment: I'd use 2 `Pattern`s and keep my life easy. Regular expressions tend to become unreadable real fast.

Comment: This is not a solution, but may comme in handy. If I have to write regular expressions I use one of this online tools to develop and test them, https://regex101.com, https://www.debuggex.com.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression. If you change case 2 to

> replace `Servlet?Template=scripts/test.js` with `Servlet?Template=scripts/test.js&Id=${Id}`

all you need to do is to check whether the source string does contain a `?` if not add `?Id=${Id}` else add `&Id=${Id}`.

After all

```
if (strTemplateText.contains("?") {
    strTemplateText += "&Id=${Id}";
}
else {
    strTemplateText += "?Id=${Id}";
}
```

does the job.

Or even shorter

```
strTemplate += strTemplateText.contains("?") ? "&Id=${Id}" : "?Id=${Id}";
```

Comment: the problem is that I'm working with a template full text , not only the text of src. what if I have several occurrence of src in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question doesn't match up so well with your example code.  The example code seems to handle a more general case, and it substitutes an actual session Id value instead of a reference to one.  The code below takes the example code to be more indicative of what you really want, but the same approach could be adapted to what you asked in the question text (using a simpler regex, even).

With that said, I don't see any way to do this with a single `replaceAll()` because the replacement text for the two cases is too different.  You could nevertheless do it with one regex, in one pass, if you used a different approach:

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(src\\s*=\\s*)(['\"])([^?]*?)(\\?.*?)?\\2",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(strTemplateText);
StringBuffer revisedText = new StringBuffer();

while (m2.find()) {
    // Append the whole match except the closing quote
    m2.appendReplacement(revisedText, "$1$2$3$4");
    // group 4 is the optional query string; null if none was matched
    revisedText.append((m2.group(4) == null) ? '?' : '&');
    revisedText.append("Id=");
    revisedText.append(CurrentESSession.getAttributeString("Id", ""));
    // append a copy of the opening quote
    revisedText.append(m2.group(2));
}
m2.appendTail(revisedText);

strTemplateText = revisedText.toString();
```

That relies on BetaRide's observation that query parameter order is not significant, although the same general approach could accommodate a requirement to make `Id` the first query parameter, as in the question.  It also matches the end of the `src` attribute in the pattern to the correct closing delimiter, which your pattern does not address (though it needs to do to avoid matching text that spans more than one `src` attribute).

Do note that nothing in the above prevents a duplicate query parameter 'Id' being added; this is consistent with the regex presented in the question.  If you want to avoid that with the above approach then in the loop you need to parse the query string (when there is one) to determine whether an 'Id' parameter is already present.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I tried your code it works for some cases but failed for other , for example : ' SRC="<if "${sd.dashDisplay}" == "yes">ShowPage?Template=apps/dash/templates/content.htm</if>" '   is being replaced by  'SRC="<if ?Id=dzpejFbIjDWxIyVh0PIZsgHL6F_47KMPUtfMl/gq_T4="no" == "yes">ShowPage?Template=apps/dash/templates/content.htm</if>" ' do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2484927, the regex I presented does not handle embedded appearances of the attribute delimiter, which I did not contemplate based on your examples.  These would not appear in an XML or HTML context, where a character entity would need to be used instead.  I'm anyway uncertain how *any* processor could handle the specific failure case you presented, as there seems no way to distinguish the embedded quotes from the terminating one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
//strTemplateText  is the Template's text
String strTemplateText = "src=\"scripts/test.js\"";
strTemplateText = "src=\"Servlet?Template=scripts/test.js\"";

java.util.regex.Pattern p2 = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(src\\s*=\\s*[\"'])(.*?)((?:[\\w\\s\\d.\\-\\#]+\\/?)+)(?:[?]?)(.*?\\=.*)*(['\"])");
java.util.regex.Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(strTemplateText);
System.out.println(m2.matches());
strTemplateText = m2.replaceAll("$1$2$3?Id=" + CurrentESSession.getAttributeString("Id", "") + (m2.group(4)==null? "":"&") + "$4$5");
System.out.println(strTemplateText);
```

It works on both cases.

> If you are using java > 1.6; then, you could use custom-named group-capturing features for making the regex exp. more human-readable and easier to debug.